# Show UIView from UIViewController as a context menu preview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios13

I am experimenting with iOS 13 and the new UIContextMenu API, and when trying to use context menu previews, I wanted to show a small card relative to the UITableRow that was pressed. I created a UIViewController in my storyboard, with a UIView inside that contains the info card itself (I made the UIView so that I can easily change its size with constraints). I tried only displaying it by doing

```swift
@IBOutlet var infoCard = UIView!
override func loadView(){
    super.loadView()
    view = infoCard
    preferredContentSize = infoCard.bounds.size
}
```

However, when showing the context menu I see the view but there are black rectangle above and below the card, since the preview's ratio isn't changed.

How would I display this info card with another ratio? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get it right, the issue I was having is that infoCard.bounds would return the storyboard value, but my view has a dynamic size and Swift doesn't try to recalculate the visible height/width until the frame was drawn. Here's the code that works to have a UIView inside a UIViewController be rendered when the UIViewController is shown in a context menu preview:

```swift
// All this is inside the view controller, with cardView being the displayed view
loadViewIfNeeded()
updateViewConstraints()

// This will force Swift to recalculate the view's size
cardView.drawHierarchy(in: cardView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

view = cardView
preferredContentSize = cardView.bounds.size
```